# Lista removiendo datos de lista padre

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Porque si ejecuto el siguiente código

```
lista = [1,2,3]

for i in lista:
    lista_modificable = lista 
    lista_modificable.remove(i)
    alguna_funcion(lista_modificable)
```

el valor de la variable "lista" se le van eliminando sus valores si en ningún momento ejecuté lista.remove(i). Acaso la variable i tiene "memoria" de la variable a la que pertenece?

Ya le hice un print a la variable "lista" y esto es lo que me sale

```
[2,3]
[2]
```

lo que implica que con cada iteración va eliminandose "lista" hasta que se queda sin datos y se corta el ciclo for.

Comment: De acuerdo, ¡Ya lo entiendo! muchísimas gracias. No acostumbro a usar stack overflow para preguntar, (puesto que generalmente mis preguntas ya fueron preguntadas y respondidas), pero, ¿hay alguna forma de señalarte como mejor respuesta o algo así?

Comment: No puedes darme puntos de reputación a través de un comentario. Tendría que haberte respondido como respuesta "real". Si quieres puedo dar una respuesta normal y extenderme un poco más.

Comment: Si gustas hacerlo y tienes tiempo, sería genial, para poder darte más reputación !

Comment: De acuerdo, de nuevo muchas gracias !

Answer (score 1):

### Respuesta breve:

Si sabes C, te ayudará a entender python el conocer que todas las variables python son en realidad punteros a los datos. La asignación `a=b` copia los punteros. En tu caso ambos acaban apuntando a la misma lista. Si lo que quieres es crear una lista nueva que sea una copia de la anterior puedes usar `lista_modificable = list(lista)`, o la versión más oscura `lista_modificable = lista[:]` que crea un *slice* con todos los elementos (y los *slices* siempre son copias).

### Respuesta larga:

En python todas las variables son referencias a posiciones de memoria donde realmente están los datos.

Esto resulta bastante chocante a quienes vengan del C, donde una variable no es más que una "etiqueta" que se refiere a una dirección de memoria, siempre la misma. Por ejemplo, si en C haces:

```
int a;
a = 2;
a = 3;
```

básicamente el identificador `a` se refiere a una posición de memoria con tamaño suficiente para albergar un entero, y después en esa posición metes primero un 2 y luego un 3 (que sobreescribe al 2). Pero la dirección a que apunta `a` es la misma en todo momento.

En cambio en Python:

```
a = 2
a = 3
```

hace algo bastante más complejo de lo que cabría esperar.

En la primera asignación:

1. Se crea un dato de tipo entero en memoria, con el valor `2`
2. Se hace que el identificador `a` "apunte" al dato recién creado. En cierta forma `a` sería equivalente a un puntero del C.

En la segunda asignación:

1. Se crea otro dato de tipo entero en memoria, con el valor `3`
2. Se cambia la dirección a que apuntaba `a`, para que ahora apunte al nuevo dato. El antiguo dato `2` sigue existiendo (en otra dirección de memoria diferente al 3), hasta que el "recolector de basura" decida eliminarlo (cosa que hace cuando detecta que no hay referencias "apuntando" a él).

Es más, la siguiente asignación:

```
b = a
```

Crea una nueva referencia (`b`) apuntando al mismo dato que apuntaba `a`. Ambos ahora apuntan al 3. Sin embargo esto no plantea ningún tipo de problema por ser el `3` "inmutable". Un 3 siempre es un 3. No puedes cambiarlo a otra cosa. Si crees que esto lo cambiará a 4:

```
a += 1
```

te equivocas y estás pensando "en C". Esa asignación toma el 3 al que "apunta" `a`, le suma 1 y con el resultado crea un nuevo dato de tipo entero, de valor 4, y cambia la referencia `a` para que apunte al nuevo dato. Mientras tanto  `b` sigue apuntando al antiguo y por tanto sigue siendo 3.

De manera que aún si tienes el modelo mental equivocado, el resultado es el esperado. `a += 1` sólo modifica `a` y no afecta a `b`.

Pero en el momento que trabajas con listas, ya que estas son *mutables* es cuando empiezan las sorpresas.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
```

Ahora, ya que `b` y `a` ambos se refieren al mismo "objeto" (la lista con valores 1, 2 y 3), cuando hagas por ejemplo `a[0]=100`, también estarás cambiando `b[0]`; cuando hagas `b.append(10)`, también lo estarás añadiendo a la lista `a`, y cuando hagas `b.remove(2)` también lo estarás quitando de la lista `a`. Ya que en realidad *solo hay una lista*.

Pero si en cambio haces `b = [30, 50]`, eso no afectará a `a`, ya que en este caso estás creando un nuevo objeto (la lista con valores 30 y 50) y *cambiando* la referencia `b` para que apunte al nuevo dato, con lo que `a` y `b` ya no estarán apuntando más a la misma lista, sino a listas diferentes.

Lo mismo ocurre si haces:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
```

Aunque tengan los mismos valores, son listas diferentes.

Python proporciona el operador `==` para comparar si tienen los mismos valores (y daría en este último ejemplo que `a==b` es `True`), y también proporciona el operador `is` para comprobar si se trata de *el mismo objeto* (básicamente, si apuntan a la misma dirección de memoria). En este último caso `a is b` daría `False`, pero si hubieses hecho `b=a` entonces `a is b` daría `True`.

### Otra cosa

Es peligroso (el resultado puede ser inesperado) el eliminar elementos de una lista que estás recorriendo en un bucle for, que es justamente lo que "sin querer" estabas haciendo en tu bucle, puesto que aunque recorres `lista` y eliminas de `lista_modificable` ambas son en realidad la misma como expliqué en el otro comentario.

El problema es que al eliminar elementos de la lista mientras la recorres puedes "confundir" al iterador python que te devuelve cuál es el siguiente elemento y puedes saltarte elementos inadvertidamente.

En [este enlace](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=lista%20%3D%20%5B1,2,3%5D%0A%0Adef%20alguna_funcion%28l%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%28len%28l%29%29%0A%0Afor%20i%20in%20lista%3A%0A%20%20%20%20lista_modificable%20%3D%20lista%20%0A%20%20%20%20lista_modificable.remove%28i%29%0A%20%20%20%20alguna_funcion%28lista_modificable%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) puedes ejecutar "paso a paso" tu programa, mientras ves una representación gráfica de los datos y las referencias. Ahí verás claramente que ambas listas son la misma, y que al eliminar elementos mientras iteras, te saltas uno.

[image: Captura ejecución]

Comment: Excelente respuesta !